# How to convert pixel value to another value based on given csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a 2D image label (value from 0 to 20). I want to change the pixel values in the image to another value based on the table in the csv file

```
Original value     New value

0                      0
1                      23
2                      2
3                      11
4                      11
5                      15
...
```

We can do it as by a simple way likes

```
label[label==0]=0
label[label==1]=23
label[label==2]=2
label[label==3|label==4]=11
label[label==5]=15
```

For above way, I need at least 20 lines for converting, and careful look at the table in CSV file to fill out the value in the conditions. Do we have a better way? I am using python 3.6

*updated:* The csv file likes

```
label1, 0, 0
label2, 1, 23
label3, 2, 2
label4, 3, 11
label5, 4, 11
label6, 5, 15
```

the first row is just the name, we do not care it

Comment: Not enough information.

Comment: You can use a dictionary where the old values are keys and new values are dictionary values. Then `new_label=csv_dict[old_label]`. The dictionary can be built from the CSV file with a `DictReader`.

Comment: thanks DyZ. could you provide some script to do it? I am not family of dictinaory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `numpy` arrays:

```
import numpy as np

Data = np.arange(25).reshape((5,5))

#Data
#array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
#       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
#       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
#       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
#       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])

switch = np.loadtxt('./test.txt', comment='#')
```

`switch` now contains 6 rows with the old number as first and the new number as second element. By looping over the number of rows we can change the pixel values:

```
for i in range(switch.shape[0]):
    Data[Data == switch[i, 0]] = switch[i, 1]

#Data
#array([[ 0, 23,  2, 11, 11],
#       [15,  6,  7,  8,  9],
#       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
#       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
#       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

test.txt:

```
#old                  new
0                      0
1                      23
2                      2
3                      11
4                      11
5                      15
```

**Edit:**

If your data is in a .csv file like in your updated question, simply tweak the `loadtxt` call:

```
switch = np.loadtxt('./text.txt', usecols=(1,2), delimiter=',')
```

This way we ignore the first column (numpy doesn't work with arrays of mixed types (float and string)) and we change the delimiter from whitespace to comma.
NOTE: The file extension is not important here, it can be either .txt or .csv or anything else. Only the file content is important.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks

Comment: of course, however, the test file is csv file. Sorry I did not mentioned in the example. So it likes `pixel1,0,0...` where pixel1 is name of pixel, 0 is old value and second 0 is new value

Comment: what do you mean by "name of pixel"?

Comment: I have update the csv file. The first row is just the name. We do not care it. Just care about the pixel value. Your solution is correct, just change from text to csv file